# Regex to matching strings Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying regex to match the names in the string below:

```
$strText = "some text, 'Frances , David', some text, 'Foljevic, Laura M', some text, Holjevic, Louis, some text, 'Staples, Cheri L', some text"
```

The name must start and end with single quotation mark(')
There can be optional space before and after comma sign(,)
There can be first, last and middle name.

I am trying to match with the following pattern: `'\w*(\s*)?, \w*(\s*\w*)?'` but it fails in case of middle name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
 $strText = "some text, 'Frances , David', some text, 'Foljevic, Laura M', some text, Holjevic, Louis, some text, 'Staples, Cheri L', some text"

    $result = 
    [regex]::Matches($strText,"'(.+?)'") |
    foreach {$_.groups[1].value}

    $result

    Frances , David
    Foljevic, Laura M
    Staples, Cheri L
```

Comment: Hi mjolinor,
Can i add output strings to some collection like $Result = @()?